# How to go to the next activivity after registration in Android

Tags: android, json

Actually I want to go to the next activity by using toast that I get from the server. In summary I want to move the user to the dashboard after get registerd. I am sending data in Jason URL. So how can I move to next activity . Can any one help me

Comment: Post some code where you handling that toast..

Comment: what do you mean by " I am sending data in Jason URL"?

Comment: Help us to help you. Minimum code please.

Comment: flagged as unclear what you're asking. Specify more and add some code or it will be really hard for us to help you. Anyway if your problem is that you don't know how to go to next activity, consider first searching on internet because there are like 2000 questions about it

Answer (score 0):

To move next activity use intents..

```
Intent i=new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,NextActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

to send data from one activity to another

```
Intent i=new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,NextActivity.class);
i.putextra("key",your value);
startActivity(i);
```

on the next Activity onCreate method

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
    if(intent!=null) {
       String value= intent.getStringExtra("key");
       Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),value,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can show the Toast

```
Toast.makeText(Registration.this,"your message",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

and then  go to next activity

```
Intent intent=new Intent(Registration.this,DashBoard.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

After getting successful response from server side you can call

Intent intent=new Intent(Registration.this,DashBoard.class);
startActivity(intent);

on post execute of your Async Task